# Play API : Change Developer Name programmatically

Tags: google-play

I've discovered the Google Play API which seems to be quite convenient for several tasks related to the APKs. However, I'd also like to change the developer name (which can be found under "Google Play Developer Console"->"Settings"->"Account Details"->"Developer Name"-Field) programmatically.

So far, I have not discovered yet how you can do this with the Play API. Therefore my question: Is is possible to update the Developer Name via e.g. a python script and without using a regular web browser?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to change your developer name via an API call. You could write a bot to do that for you, but I don't know if you are allowed to that.

However if you are going to write a bot I would recommend you using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)